# Spring Cloud Gateway transforming authorization

Tags: spring-security, client-certificates, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a case where frontend is sending JWT token with authorized user data and for each request Spring Cloud Gateway needs to create a x509 client certificate for that user and use that to call backend services. Something like TokenRelay filter but create a connection with client certificate.

The client certificate is build based on other certificate with CN taken from JWT properties.
This needs to happen on the fly, without storing it.

Any hints where to look for a hook in SCG?

**Solution:**

Overwrite bean method NettyRoutingFilter.getHttpClient()
method is called each request and has access to ServerWebExchange.

inside we call super that gives us HttpClient instance, then we go for client.secure(sslContextSpec) where we pass SSL setup.
in return we get a new ssl aware HttpClient instance.

Comment: This is not really a spring security/cloud-gateway problem and there is no out of the box solution provided by spring. This is mostly a system design problem and I am fairly certain it can't be made to work with dynamic x509 client certificate. It is certainly possible to build keystore/truststore at runtime in java but the problem you have is getting server to verify it. When try and build dynamic certificate at runtime how does server know and trust it? In x509 based auth server and client both know and trust each other which can't be done with dynamically generated certificates at runtime.

Comment: Backend verifies the x509 certificate based on issuer cert mainly, that is common to both sides, tested with postman.